# Titanium - Change imageview using picker

Tags: image, mobile, replace, imageview, titanium

I am trying to change an imageview to a new image based on a "change" event. When i attempt this event with the current code, i get a an error-  "invalid image type. expected either TiBlob or TiFile, was: NSNull in -[TiUIImageView setImage_:] (TiUIImageView.m:693)

```
//This label contains text that will change with each picker change
var results = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
text:"Select from the picker below",
height:40,
width:"auto",
top:20  
});

//This view contains an image that will change with each picker change
var imageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({   
        image:"images/logos/CIK.jpg",
        height: 100, 
        width: 100, 
        left: 110,
        top: 80
    });

picker.addEventListener("change", function(e){
results.text = e.row.title + ": Home of the " + e.row.val;
imageView.image = e.row.logo; //logo contains a value like images/logos/BURRTON.jpg
});

win.add(results);
win.add(imageView);

win.open();
```

Seems like this should be easy to do, but i am stumped. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to set `backgroundImage` instead of image?

Comment: backgroundImage didn't change either. I also used URL.

Comment: I dont know if your image path is correct or e.row.logo is showing correct path. But one thing you can try more is to use `View` instead of `imageView` and set a `backgroundImage` then see what happens.

Comment: Muhammad, Thank you! I changed it to a view and changed the background image and that worked out great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `View` instead of `imageView` and set a `backgroundImage`.